# Quartz dont recover Job

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I use:

- Spring 4.2.9
- PostgreSQL
- Quartz 2.3.0
- Java 8

I have some problems with recovery job in cluster servers... I have 2 test servers in cluster (1 DB).

Scheduler work fine, but when I stop tomcat (1) where Job is running, on another server (2) job is not recover...

If I restart tomcat #2, then scheduler start work, if I start tomcat #1, when tomcat #2 work, quartz take work to tomcat #1. Work very good, but

First question: I need when tomcat #1 is stopped, tomcat #2 will be start Job without restart...

Second question: And what **jdbcjobstore** better for me? **JobStoreTX** or **JobStoreCMT** ? In work cluster, i have 4 server on Spring 4.2.9

Sorry for my English and Thank you very much for you answers!

Properties Quartz, @Bean in my project

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("org.quartz.threadPool.class","org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool");
prop.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "4");
prop.put("org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "20000");
prop.put("quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "ServerScheduler");
prop.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "AUTO");
prop.put("org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck", "true");
prop.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "IS_CLUSTERED");
prop.put("org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class","org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory");
prop.put("org.quartz.jobStore.class","org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT");
prop.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass","org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate");
prop.put("org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "myDS");
prop.put("org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource", "myDS");
prop.put("org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "QRTZ_");
prop.put("org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered", "true");
prop.put("org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
prop.put("org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL", url);
prop.put("org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user", user);
prop.put("org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password", password);
prop.put("org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections", "4");
```

My Job and Trigger

```
JobDetail job = newJob(QuartzStockTask.class)
                .withIdentity("Job " + "1", "Job group " + "11")
                .requestRecovery(true)
                .build();

Trigger sTrigger1 = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("Trig " + "1", "Trig group " + "11")
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .repeatForever())
                .build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(job, sTrigger1);
```

Comment: In first time I used JobStoreTX and problem was same, i tried use JobStoreCMT, but it not help...

Comment: are you using the default for "org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval"? This determines how often the instances check in. If this value is large in your setting, then server 2 may not yet detect server 1 is down.

Comment: I tried your solution but did not help

Answer (score 0):

I found problem, it was double org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId, in first time is AUTO and second IS_CLUSTERED.
Thank all of you!

Comment: BUT 2 question stay is open! JobStoreTX or JobStoreCMT ?

Comment: From the javadocs, since you are running this part of tomcat container JobStoreCMT [http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/JobStoreCMT.html ] should be preferred.